# css logo link not working on IE or firefox

Tags: css, hyperlink, overflow, hidden

I tried everything I know and I can't find out why on IE and Firefox the link underneath the logo ("next meeting or event") does not work at all. Here is my css:

```
/*logo*/
.nav-logo {
float:left;
width: 260px;
margin-left: .2em;
z-index: 1;}

.nav-logo top {
float:left;
width: 250px;
cursor: pointer;}

.event {
float:left;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top:-8px;
cursor: pointer;
clear: both;}


/* Nav width setting*/
.nav-hold {
width: 98%;
max-width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;}

/* NAVIGATION */
.nav-bar {
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
background-image:url(../images/bg-menu80.jpg);}

.nav-hold {
overflow:hidden;}

.nav-list {
float: right;
list-style: none;}

.nav-list li {
float: left;
width: auto;
position: relative;}

.nav-list li a {
text-decoration: none;
display:block;
padding: 30px 7px 28px 7px;
color: #f9f9f9;
font-size: .9em;
font-weight: bold;}

.nav-list li ul {
display: none;
list-style: none;
position: absolute;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 70px;}

.nav-list li ul li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;}

.nav-list li:hover ul {
display: block;}

.nav-list li a:hover li {
float: left;}

.nav-list li:hover li a {
background-color: #333;
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
color: #FFF;
height:50px;
width:150px;}

.nav-list li a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
padding: 30px 7px 28px 7px;
color: #000;
font-size: .9em;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: #e7e4e4;}
```

I hope I'm writing the code here correctly, please you can see the page here:
http://www.vosgrafica.com/LIEG/index.html

Thanks to all, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

`<div id="sidebar">` is in front of the link. Change its z-index to a lower value.

Comment: Hi Christine and thank you! I tried your suggestion and the navigation appear without the background image and the logo in the wrong position... any other idea?   thank you again!

Comment: Hello Rigo. Sorry, I don't know what you mean by "wrong position". It looks right for me and your link works now, too.